# Under what conditions the set $A$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, connectedness

Let $f:ℝ^{m}→ℝ$ is a continuous function. Let us consider the set $$A=\{x∈ℝ^{m} \ |\ f(x)=0\} = f^{-1}[\{0\}]$$

My question is: Under what conditions the set $A$ is connected?, simply connected?

Comment: Convexity might be relevant here. Not sure though.

Comment: The exact conditions are of course whenever $f$ has the property that $f^{-1}(0)$ is connected/simply connected. I doubt there is some other meaningful property of $f$ that is equivalent to that...

Comment: Convexity of $f$ is not enough. For example $f(x)=x^2-2$ would be counterexample. In higher dimensions, this example does not work though.

Comment: Not sure if we can conclude (any topological properties of $A$) if $m > 1$ and if $f$ isn't bijective, if I'm wrong I'm **really** interested to see a counter example